# Is there a way to catch the exception thrown from boost::promise when setting it while it's already set?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future, boost-thread

I have a program that uses a timer to set some double buffer in a GUI application. Under some rare circumstances, e.g., while the program is shutting down, I get an error that the promise that sets this buffer is already set. Is there a way to catch that error and deal with it?

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::promise<int> promise;
    try {
        promise.set_value(0);
        promise.set_value(0);
    } catch (...) {
        promise.set_exception(boost::current_exception());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No matter how I try to catch it, it terminates my program with error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::promise_already_satisfied> >'
```

And [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/211bc01de901c2e2) you can see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `set_value` another `set_value` fails and I bet the `set_exception` in your catch block fails with the same reason: the result (either value or exception) is already set, the promise is already satisfied. At least that is how [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) works and I would not be surprised if `boost::promise` works the same.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Wrapping the promise set with its own try/catch solved the problem.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Which set? The `set_exception` in the catch block? That in fact should fix it.

Comment: The `set_value()`, which triggers the problem.